# Error during npm start files not found

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new to electron and I am trying to get it up and running on my machine. I am trying to follow along with a tutorial titled 'Creating Your First Desktop App With HTML, JS and Electron'.

I set up the folder where I wanted the files to be downloaded to and extracted them to it but after running npm intall (I did the npm start) an error showed up. this log came back. Please help me understand how to properly install or give file names need to make electron run.

I am using a windows 10 x64 machine.

**here is the log**

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'start' ]

2 info using npm@3.10.5

3 info using node@v4.4.7

4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Desktop\WestHelper\package.json'

4 verbose stack     at Error (native)

5 verbose cwd c:\Users\Desktop\WestHelper

6 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586

7 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
"C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

8 error node v4.4.7

9 error npm  v3.10.5

10 error path c:\Users\Desktop\WestHelper\package.json

11 error code ENOENT

12 error errno -4058

13 error syscall open

14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Desktop\WestHelper\package.json'

15 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Desktop\WestHelper\package.json'

15 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

15 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.

16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

Answer (score 1):

the idea behind NPM is to install packages from package.json shipped with application, so everybody can download dependencies and packages used in project. Because of this, when you run npm install, it searches current directory for file named package.json and tries to read dependency tree from it. The message you posted says, it could not find any in directory *c:\Users\Desktop\WestHelper\package.json*

If I've found correct tutorial, there is a section called *How it’s made* where the content **package.json** file is present.

Hope it helped, have a wonderful day.
T

Comment: Thanks..... could you give more detail explanation. Is more than just changing the values in package.json file. I have tried that. also did npm install npm -g to get latest.

Comment: What you got in mind by "more detail explanation" ? Does updating the contents of package.json solves the error you described above ? If not, what seems to be the problem ? :)

Comment: thanks....the reason for that error is because package.json was in another folder inside the project I corrected that. now I am getting "cannot find module 'app' "  at module_resolveFilename(Module.js: 440:15).....